# How to make phonegap push notification in multiple language

Tags: notifications, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, push, phonegap-pushplugin

My objective is to show push notification which is done with GCM in language other than english.My project is with HTML and jquery.And i am using phonegap push plugin.

Comment: your question is not clear. Do you want to auto change the notification language or want to change the language manually.

Comment: @Dron I want to make push notification in gujarati (language in india).

Comment: my question is you want to change langue automatically or manually